# Operational amplifier driving too much current

Tags: operational-amplifier, current, analog

I have an operational amplifier (OPA2344PA) circuit like the one below:

[image]

I'm obtaining the 3.3 V from a power supply. When I power the circuit, I can see in my power supply that 40 mA are being driven. I have measured the current flowing from the 3.3 V to the pin 8 (positive supply) and it's true that those 40 mA are flowing.

According to the [OPA2344 datasheet](https://rocelec.widen.net/view/pdf/fsllthxnf6/sbos107a.pdf?t.download=true&u=5oefqw), its expected quiescent current is in the order of uA, so 40 mA is way too much.

Am I right assuming that 40 mA is way too much? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Something is certainly wrong. If you have the chip turned 180 degrees that would explain it.

Comment: Maybe the problem is that the negative power supply terminal is connected to ground? Do I need to bias it to Vcc/2? @td127

Comment: No, that's perfectly fine. You do want to make sure the other opamp in the package is terminated, e.g. short pins 1,2 and tie pin 3 to something (pin 5, ground).

Comment: @dan, if you ‘biased’ the negative rail to vcc/2 then your input voltages would exceed the negative rail. Not recommended.

Comment: I have shorted pins 1,2 (out A and -In A respectively) and tied oin 3 to ground, and get the same result. Is there any problem in not having any load at all at the output?

Comment: No, your circuit is fine as drawn - it should draw less than one mA. Either what you've wired isn't what your schematic shows, or the chip is in backwards, or the chip is bad, or the chip isn't what you think it is, or your meter isn't correct or you're reading it wrong, or there's another load on your power supply, or something else I haven't thought of.

Comment: I have tried again with another OPA2344 I have and everything works now; I get ~1.6V at the output and the op. amp. drives ~6 uA. However, at first I didn't have the other op. amp. in the package terminated as you said @td127 I wonder if this is what broke my other op. amp., although I always exposed it to those 40 mA for less than ~2 seconds.

Comment: I'm glad you were able to solve your problem. I'd be very surprised if leaving opamp pins unconnected were enough to have the chip self destruct - I suspect some other cause. But at any rate, your question is resolved so you should probably close it, or supply an answer yourself and accept it, otherwise this item will linger as an unresolved zombie for years on end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in the comments, the problem was that the op. amp. was damaged. This could be caused by the fact that it didn't have its second op. amp. (the package comes with 2) terminated, although this is not very probable.

Comment: It's more likely it just oscillates because it is not connected, rather than damage when not connected.